# Почему не срабатывает preg_match()?

Tags: preg_match, php

Почему не срабатывает? Мне нужно, чтобы проверяло на полное наличие слова.

```
if(!preg_match("/^Почта$/", file_get_contents($url))) echo '';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам решил свою проблему. Надо было так:

```
preg_match("#Почта#ies", file_get_contents($url))
```

Comment: Зачем Вам столько совершенно лишних модификаторов?  
> e (PREG_REPLACE_EVAL) 
Если используется данный модификатор, preg_replace() после выполнения стандартных подстановок в заменяемой строке интерпретирует ее как PHP-код и использует результат для замены искомой строки. Одинарные и двойные кавычки, обратные слэши (\) NULL-символы будут проэкранированы обратными слэшами в подставляемых обратных ссылках.
Вы используете строку как код?

Comment: > s (PCRE_DOTALL) 
Если данный модификатор используется, метасимвол "точка" в шаблоне соответствует всем символам, включая перевод строк. Без него - всем, за исключением переводов строк. Этот модификатор эквивалентен записи /s в Perl. Класс символов, построенный на отрицании, например [^a], всегда соответствует переводу строки, независимо от наличия этого модификатора.


В Вашем выражении нет точки, а зачем не нужен этот модификатор.

Comment: Проще и эффективнее было бы воспользоваться [`stripos()`](http://php.net/stripos).

    if (stripos(file_get_contents($url), 'Почта') === false) {
        // ...
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!preg_match("#Почта#", file_get_contents($url))) echo '';
```

так попробуй

```
if(!preg_match("/\Почта\/isU", file_get_contents($url))) echo '';
```

Comment: @johniek_comp, тогда если прописать "Поч", то тоже найдёт. Мне надо, чтобы был полный поиск, а не так, чтобы часть ввёл и прохляло.

Comment: @ModaL, обновил

Comment: @johniek_comp, всегда echo '', даже если найден..

Answer (score 1):

preg_match_all ?